# Get duration time and update in table in mysql store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have time string like my blow code and i want to compare that time to time now and then if duration is longer than 15minutes i will update one field in my table

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `EXPIRESESSION`()
wholeblock:BEGIN
    declare str VARCHAR(900) default '';
    SET str='2019-06-13 09:56:44,2019-06-13 13:49:46,';
    WHILE (LOCATE(',', str) > 0)
    DO
    SET @value = ELT(1, str);
    SET str= SUBSTRING(str, LOCATE(',',str) + 1);
        SET @duration=(SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, (SELECT B.logtime FROM users B WHERE B.logtime IS NOT NULL), NOW()));
        IF(@duration>15) THEN           
            UPDATE users SET logtime =null where logtime = str;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: Great and the question is?

Comment: @P.Salmon i can't update my table that condition is match with my record in db.

Comment: Please add your user table definition and sample data would be nice.